# How to handle HTTP requests

Tags: c++, sockets, http, webserver

When a browser requests a web page, the browser will send a lot of requests. How do you need to handle these requests? Can I accept all those pages multi-threaded and send the result back (With send  locking), or do I need to accept only 1 packet and send the result, accept another packet and send the result?

Comment: At simplest, loading a webpage is one request and one response. Client requests one content with GET and server responses with status 200 and that content, if it is available

Comment: @Gjordis So the answer is that I need to send the result back at the same order I received? Because I will get multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: If you are making a server, yes. The question does not really specify the use of the server, or the usual user amounts, or much of anything. Most servers thread new requests to a limit.

Comment: @Gjordis I'm implementing the web server. It's about a normal page request. There can be multiple users at the same time. So I need to make a queue for every user (IP), and send results back with the first in first out order. Thanks!

Comment: @Dagob: No you don't. You do not even need to care if it is the same user (in fact you can't even tell if it is the same user solely by the ip). You simply answer per request. And it does not matter in which order you answer the requests.

Comment: Please do look at the links I cited below.  Please add "cookies" to your study list.  And please (please!) consider using an existing web server (like Apache) or web programming library (like Microsoft INet) before writing your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest brushing up on some of the basics of TCP/IP networking, sockets programming and the HTTP protocol before you go too much further.

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Check out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

2) Here are a few links on HTTP and how it works:

- http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/
- http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http

3) First, I would definitely get a copy of Wireshark and trace a couple of simple HTTP requests and responses between your browser and some server:

- http://www.wireshark.org

IMHO...